# Change branch parent

Tags: git

Have following branches structure:

```
                       master
                     /       \
                BranchA      BranchB
```

But it should be:

```
                 master
                  /           
            BranchA        
               /
         BranchB
```

Could anyone advice how to re-hang BranchB as child of BranchA?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You want to use [rebase](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing). With BranchB checked-out, do

```
git rebase BranchA
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this using `Bitbucket`?

Comment: @akash, you can download `Git for Windows` and go to the repository in the `bash console` and run the required commands (assuming that your BitBucket repo is `Git`)

Comment: Just for fun, Everyone replying on this answer is Akash

Answer (score 7):

```
git checkout branchB; git rebase branchA;
```

will do this for you. bear in mind if this has been pushed somewhere else, you'll screw up the history.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `git rebase -i`(interactive mode) to edit the whole history, which commit you want as the starting point of new branch rebase, the commit message, etc.

In your case, if you desired situation is:

```
             master
              /           
        BranchA        
           /
     BranchB
```

but on branchA you already have some commits:

```
             master
              /           
        BranchA
           |
        commit A1
           |
        commit A2
```

You may want to choose the A1 as starting point of branchB, not A2(the latest, where the HEAD of A is), then `git rebase -i` can help.